# Keras batch_dot dimension question in loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am creating a custom loss function. In the terminal I can make this code, which works perfectly

```
import keras.backend as K
q = K.ones(shape=(32,100,3))
k = K.ones(shape=(32,100,3))
s = 0
for i in range(0, int(q.shape[0]) ):
    s += K.sum(K.batch_dot(q[i], k[i], axes=[1,1] ))
print (K.get_value(s))
```

> 9600.0

So I adapted this to the loss function

```
def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    s = 0
    for i in range(0, int(y_true.shape[0]) ):
        s += K.sum(K.log(K.batch_dot(y_true[i], y_pred[i], axes=[1,1] )))
    return -s
```

But then I get this error message:
[image]

I am assuming that the `y_true.shape` is not working how I would expect inside the loss function. Does anyone know how I can fix the code to accomplish the same sum inside the loss function?

Thanks!

EDIT

Here is an explanation of the calculation I need to create inside the loss function. I know it may seems strange but this is what i need to create. Here is an example as if it were calculated with numpy arrays.

```
y_true = np.ones([2,3,4])
y_pred = np.ones([2,3,4])
running_sum = 0
for i in range(0,y_true.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,y_pred.shape[1]):
        running_sum += np.log( y_true[i,j] @ y_pred[i,j] )
print( running_sum )
```

Comment: Can you describe the operation that batch dot is doing inside the loop? (Batch dot is a very weird function with very weird results, if you describe the operation I'm sure there are very easy options to do this). (Yes, I'm aware the problem is that `shape` is returning a tensor, not a python tuple, but the solution should definitely avoid any loops)

Comment: @DanielMöller Thanks. I updated the question is an example of the calculation.

Comment: What is `@`????

Comment: @DanielMöller @ is the dot product in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, considering your edit:

- assuming that in the 2D loop you're taking vectors with shape `(4,)`
- assuming that the `@` operator is a scalar product or dot product

This is as simple as:

```
dot = K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=-1)
dotlog = K.log(dot)
return K.sum(dotlog)
```

If you intend to later use some sort of function that depends on individualized samples (like sample weights, for instance) you can:

```
return K.sum(..., axis=1)
```

---

You might also like using `keras.losses.cosine_proximity(y_true, y_pred, axis=-1)`

Comment: Yes your understanding of my edit is all correct, however I'm sorry I left one important piece out of the edit, which I fixed now. This the example, the vectors of length 4 which I am performing the dot product, I need to take the log of the result of each product. I think in this case the straight sum as you suggested will not work. Sorry my error there. Not sure if you have another idea?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind, answer fixed.